# Asp.net mvc checkbox checked from the action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

Question: I have to check the checkbox(which is not part of model) from the action ?
If I select the checkbox and submit to post action, then call the view again the checkbox will be checked fine. But how to check it on first place from non-post action please ? Thanks!

```
public ActionResult Images(string params)
{
//some code
return View(cp);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Images(string chbx)
{
//some code
}
```

Images view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.CheckBox("chbx")
}
```

I'm using MVC3 by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you mean `@Html.CheckBox("chbx", true)` ?

Comment: Will this make checkbox always be checked ?

Comment: Every pageload, yeah. Do you mean that it is actually part of the model somehow?